# creating frames like google's images page

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

How is it possible to create something like on google images? I don't understand how the left menu is fixed there, while the scroll bar affects the images only. How is this done? Is the left menu fixed positioned? Are there some sort of frames separating them both? or?

Answer (score 0):

Google images doesn't currently use iframes or frames. The left bar and the main content area are both `<div>`'s. The left `<div>` is posited:fixed, and the right `<div>` is offset by a left margin which is equal to the width of the left div.

This means the left appears to stay still while you scroll down the page.

If you are using Firefox download the addon Firebug. It will allow you to look through and examine the code in an easy way. It's a fantastic way to learn.